# multiple parameters in @selector in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, selector

If this is the method name which has to be called:

```
-(Authenticate_Obj)Authenticate_User:(NSString*)Number:(NSString*)name:(NSString*)password
```

how to call this method from the @selector ??

can i do it in this way??

```
[tis_obj AuthenticateMobileServer:self action:@selector(AuthenticateUser:::)];
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris pointed correct syntax to declare selector for a method with multiple parameters is

```
@selector(Authenticate_User:Number:name:)
```

However you can't call a method that takes more then 1 parameter using the `-performSelector` method (and similar) - you have to use the [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for that

Comment: That isn't right... easy mistake to make given the non-standard declaration.

Comment: hm, where the mistake is? (I assumed that there's Authenticate_User parameter name missing in declaration)

Comment: The selector is incorrect.  Given his declaration, it is `Authenticate_User:::`.  The `number`, `name` and `password` bits are argument names.

Answer (score 7):

Given this:

```
-(Authenticate_Obj)Authenticate_User:(NSString*)Number:(NSString*)name:(NSString*)password
```

Your method's selector is:

```
Authenticate_User:::
```

Which is the string you would pass to `@selector()`.

Your `AuthenticateMobileServer:action:` method must takes a selector that, when called, takes that set of arguments, obviously.

There are, however, several problems with this code (the first clue being the two wrong answers from otherwise very knowledgeable folk).

1. Method names do not start with capital letters, nor do they have `_`s in them.  Method names are camel-cased.   So, something like `authenticateUserNumber:name:password:` would be a more appropriate method name.
2. Every argument should have a part of the method name that describes it.   Again, `authenticateUserNumber:name:password:` would be in line with standard practice.
3. Class names don't have `_` in them.  I'm assuming Authenticate_Obj is a class.   If so, it also needs to be returned as a pointer.

Namely, that method should probably be something like:

```
- (AuthenticateObject *) authenticateUserNumber: (NSString*) aNum
                                           name: (NSString *) aName
                                       password: (NSString *) aPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this: `@selector(Authenticate_User:Number:name:)`

Answer (score 0):

Send a `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`, that contains all the needed infos as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `NSInvocation`:

```
SEL selector = @selector(Authenticate_User:Number:name:);
NSMethodSignature * ms = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:ms];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setSelector:selector];
[inv setArgument:&param1 atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&param2 atIndex:3];
[inv setArgument:&param3 atIndex:3];
[inv invoke];
Authenticate_Obj * returnObject = nil;
[inv getReturnValue:&returnObject];
```

I suggest you to check the Erica Sadun's github repository called [NSObject-Utility-Categories](https://github.com/erica/NSObject-Utility-Categories/blob/master/NSObject%2BFrankenstein.m) to check more examples of code with `NSInvocation`.